# Symmetric encryption Java passing nonce

Tags: java, rmi, encryption-symmetric

I currently have one method that is running on my SERVER SIDE that returns a randomly generated string that looks like this;

```
public String returnString(){
        String randString = nextSessionId();
        return randString;      
}
```

On my CLIENT SIDE I have a method that asks for a randomString from the SERVER, encrypts it with the client's key, seals it in a SealedObject and then replies with the SealedObject, it looks like this;

```
public boolean validateClient(String loggedInKey) throws Exception{

    /* Testing */
    String randString = this.aI.returnString(); // Client requests a string/ server returns
    System.out.println("This is what the server gave me: "+randString);

    String encryptionKey = loggedInKey;
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    SealedObject sealedClientReply = new SealedObject(randString, ecipher); // Client encrypts returned string seals it
    System.out.println("This is what I'm sending back: "+sealedClientReply);
    if(this.aI.clientValidate(sealedClientReply, loggedInKey)){
        System.out.println("Client validated!");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }       
}
```

I then have a method on my SERVER that takes this SealedObject, unseals it and uses the Client's key that it shares with it to decrypt the SealedObject, hopefully producing the same key that the Server sent to the client, it looks like this;

```
public boolean clientValidate(SealedObject sealedClientReply, String loggedInKey) throws Exception{ 

    String encryptionKey = loggedInKey;
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    sealedClientReply.getObject(dcipher); // Server decrypts object
    System.out.println("I received this from the client: "+sealedClientReply);
    String decryptedClientReply= (String) sealedClientReply.getObject(dcipher);
    System.out.println("This is what I received decrypted: "+decryptedClientReply);


    //if(decryptedClientReply.equals(randString)){
    //  return true;
    //}else{
    //  return false;
    //}
    return true;
}
```

In my mind this approach worked great, and was very secure. However I now have one major flaw. As you can see in the commented out code in the last method, the decryptedClientReply cannot equal the randString, because the method that is doing this compare doesn't actually know what randString the server sent to the client in the first place.

If I pass the randString into this method, is it still secure? If it is not secure is there another way I could carry out this symmetric approach?

Comment: In my opinion it is save, but it depends on what you want to do. if you want to validate the client you have to compare the random generated string with the decrypted string from the client. so it is necessary to keep track of the string you deliver to the client before. but be careful if there can be more than one client per server and store the strings seperately for each client

Comment: Why aren't you using TLS like everybody else?